# Генерация случайных чисел на CUDA-девайсе

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, распараллеливание, cuda

Я пишу на CUDA c++ 10.0. У меня есть массив на девайсе, который мне нужно регулярно заполнять новыми случайными числами. Для этого я написал kernel, с использованием параллелизации и прочего. Для генерации случайных чисел я решил использовать библиотеку `thrust::random`.

Допустим, мне надо заполнить массив из 100 чисел, и я это разбиваю на условные 10 блоков по 10 потоков. Получается вот такой кернель:

```cpp
__global__ void gen(float* a, thrust::minstd_rand rng)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(-10,10);
  a[index] = dist(gen);
 }
```

Сам вызов функции выглядит так:

```cpp
int main()
{
  
  // инициализация devA на девайсе
  // ...
  
  thrust::minstd_rand rgen(time(0)); // нужно каждый раз разное, поэтому инициализируем временем системы
  
  
  gen<<<bloks, threads>>>(devA, rgen); // собственно вызов

  // ...
  
}
```

Сначала вопрос, где размещаются переменные, объявленные в кернеле, сразу на девайсе? `thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist` и `int index` уже на девайсе, или как то там внутри бегают между CPU/GPU?

И, собственно, сам вопрос. Данная функция уже написана неправильно, так каждый вызов этой функции копирует себе состояние rgen, соответственно получаем много повторяющихся значений. Так же не уверен, что создание `dist` внутри кернеля целесообразно. Как вариант избежать копирований - `rng` передавать в виде ссылки на этот самый генератор, но тогда он должен находиться на девайсе, а еще, скорее всего, появится race condition, когда все потоки обратятся к этому генератору чуть ли не одновременно. Помогите разобраться, что с этим можно сделать? Или может быть я вообще не в ту сторону это делаю?

Скажу уточню, в итоге мне нужно генерировать огромные массивы случайных чисел, постоянно в ходе жизненного цикла программы, поэтому избавляться от параллелизма куды и запускать все в единственном блоке\потоке - очень нежелательно.

Comment: В вопросе явно не хватает конкретики. ¿"огромные" - это сколько в байтах и как часто? ¿Случайные - это любые псевдослучайные или криптографически приемлимые?

Comment: @user7860670, огромные - это у меня есть, допустим, 10гб на девайсе, есть вот этот массив и еще 3-4 int\bool\float таких же размеров, и чем больше впихну, тем лучше. В общем, 1+миллион. Как часто - в одной итерации всего 4 примерно равнозначных цикла, обновление рандомных значений - один из. Итераций от 50 до трех-четырех дней работы программы. Случайные - любые псевдослучайные, что бы при каждом запуске программы результат немного менялся, этого вполне достаточно, "взломом" этой последовательности заниматься никто никогда не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришел к варианту, (вроде как) решающему проблему. Вариант - создать массив генераторов, каждый из которых будет работать для своего потока. Да, для каждого "объекта" будет существовать собственный набор генераторов. Код:

```cpp
__global__ void initGen(thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float>* dist, thrust::minstd_rand rgn, time_t seed)     // seed - берется извне из time(0)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  rgn[index] = thrust::minstd_rand(seed + index * 10000);         //index добавляется для различий в сидах разных потоков\генераторов.
  gen[index] = thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(-10,10);
 }

__global__ void doGen(float* a, thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float>* dist, thrust::minstd_rand rgn)     
{
  int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  a[index] = (*dist)(gen[index]);
}

int main()
{
  
  // инициализация devA на девайсе
  // ...
  
  thrust::minstd_rand *devRgn;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&devRgn, sizeof(thrust::minstd_rand) * size); // size -> of array
  // аналогично для uniform_real_distribution 
  
  
  int seedTime = time(0);
  initGen<<<blocks, threads>>>(devDist, devRgen, seed); 

  for(/*loop*/){
    doGen<<<blocks, threads>>>(devA, devDist, devRgen);
    // ... do smth with devA
  }

  // ...
  // free/cudaFree
  
}
```

Собственно, все генераторы записываются на девайс (даже не так, они создаются и живут только там) и занимают там место. Насколько рационально это по использованию памяти - не знаю, sizeof() пишет 4 и 8 для minstd_rand и uniform_real_distribution соответственно. Это аналогично трем дополнительным `float`/`int` на один "объект". Насколько приемлемо по реальной эффективности - посмотрим.